# Which versions of SQL Server does LINQ to SQL support?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Can SQL Server 2000 be used as the database for LINQ to SQL?

Does LINQ to SQL rely on a specific version of Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, LINQ to SQL works with SQL Sever 2000 with one exception: you do need the ROW_NUMBER() function, available only in SQL Server 2005/2008, to support efficient server-side paging.  Without it, paging functions (as Mehrdad points out) are delivered using the classic Top N strategy - *very* inefficient as you page further and further through your dataset because you end up throwing out most of your selected records from the third page on.

Comment: It is also available in 2000 but it is less efficient. LINQ to SQL uses a nested SELECT TOP n statement for that case instead.

Comment: Hi Mehrdad - good tip but you are right, that grows very inefficient very quickly as you page through the dataset!

Comment: But it's still much better than paging on the client side.

Comment: There are also a few extra differences and tweaks such as varchar(max) not being supported on SQL 2000 too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

LINQ to SQL adapts the generated queries to work with 2000.

Comment: Me too...the answer was basically correct so I upvoted you to get rid of the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

As of VS 2010, L2S for SQL Server 2000 is *not* supported under any scenario (although some third party tools add support back).