# LinqToSql - Necessary to generate .dbml for each SQL Server version?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm developing an application that needs to operate against SQL server 2003, 2005, and 2008.  I'd like to transition from using T-SQL stored procedures to using Linq, as we currently don't have a database programmer, and thus making any fixes or adding any features is a slow, difficult process.  In contrast, working with LinqToSql in other projects has been a breeze.

**Will a .dbml file generated against SQLServer 2008 work if used against previous versions of SQL Server, assuming the table structures are the same?**

As we already have to support three slightly different database schemas, having to generate a DataContext for each SQL version, along with our additional data layer functionality, would be a showstopper.

Comment: what's keeping you from just trying?

Comment: Don't have access to those older versions of SQL Server, but we can't force customers to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2005, 2008: **No problems**.

SQL Server 2000, 2003: **Issues with server side paging (.Skip(), .Take()), but other than that, no**.

I am developing on a SQL Server 2005 and hosting the live system on a SQL Server 2008 without any hiccups.

You will experience problems with anything earlier than SQL Server 2005 and LINQ to SQL's implementation of .Skip() if you were ever to use it, as LINQ to SQL translates it to ROW_NUMBER in T-SQL - and this is only a part of SQL Server 2005 and onward.

See this related question: [Which versions of SQL Server does LINQ to SQL support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452050/which-versions-of-sql-server-does-linq-to-sql-support)